# jquery form submit via button with value

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form where the user can type something or just continue via ahrefs.

What I deperately search: if the user clicks the ahrefs to submit the form, can I pass some values per ahref?

```
    <form role="form" id="profiler-form"  name="profiler-form">
      <input type="hidden" id="profiler_data" name="profiler_data" value="3487">
      <input type="hidden" id="profiler_username" name="profiler_username" value="user_3839483948">
      <input type="hidden" id="profiler_password" name="profiler_password" value="user_3839483948">
      <input name=v type=hidden value=undefined>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hello" id="hello" placeholder="hello">

    <!-- a click on this link should post some value -->
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" value="mot-yet">not yet</a>

    <!-- a click on this link should post some value -->
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" value="never">never</a>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Please wait...">Signup</button>
        </form>
```

this would be a fiddle for my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/heikoeckert/4t6k8vb2/1/#&togetherjs=Ih4AdzhyAN

Thanks for any help!

Comment: pass values to where? can you give us the example of your goal?

Comment: the ahref submits the form. If someone clicks the ahref #1 to submit the form - the form should submit "1",  If someone clicks the ahref #2 to submit the form - the form should submit "2" - you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can not simple pass the argument in `submit` method, but you can do thing like this :

```
 $('#profiler-form').trigger('submit', [ { 'variable_name': true } ]);
```

on the ahref click you can invoke some method, and in this method you can trigger submit method manually with the parameter also.